# Error: Unable to create a constant value of type . Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with a selectListItem and Linq in asp.net mvc4.

**this is my model**

```
namespace RedistribucionDeCostos.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class TUsuario
    {
        public int PkUsuarioId { get; set; }
        public string UsuarioContrasena { get; set; }
        public string UsuarioRol { get; set; }
        public string UsaurioReportarTiempo { get; set; }
        public string UsuarioRedistribuirCosto { get; set; }
        public string UsuarioSituacion { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime UsuarioFechaCreacion { get; set; }
        public int FkUsuario_EmpleadoId { get; set; }

        public virtual TEmpleado TEmpleado { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**my controller file**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        if(string.Compare(Session["Rol"].ToString(),"USER") != 0){
            var query = from empleado in db.TEmpleado
                        where !(from usuario in db.TUsuario
                                from empleado2 in db.TEmpleado
                                where usuario.FkUsuario_EmpleadoId == empleado2.PkEmpleadoId
                                select usuario.FkUsuario_EmpleadoId).Contains(empleado.PkEmpleadoId)                  
                    && empleado.EmpleadoSituacion.CompareTo('A') == 0
                    select new {empleado.PkEmpleadoId, empleado.EmpleadoNombre, empleado.EmpleadoApellido };


            List<SelectListItem> opciones = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach(var item in query){
                opciones.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = (item.EmpleadoApellido+" "+item.EmpleadoApellido), Value = item.PkEmpleadoId.ToString() });
            }

            ViewBag.FkUsuario_EmpleadoId = opciones;

            return View();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

html razor file

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="color-primary">Empleado</label>
   @Html.DropDownList("FkUsuario_EmpleadoId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.FkUsuario_EmpleadoId,String.Empty, new {@class = "form-control"})
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TEmpleado)
</div>
```

The for-each throw me an error:

> "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Answer (score 0):

the error was in the linQ query.
I was put

```
empleado.EmpleadoSituacion.CompareTo('A') == 0
```

'A' is a chat type, CompareTo accept string, I change this stament for

```
empleado.EmpleadoSituacion.CompareTo("A") == 0
```

and its works!!!!!.

(bad english sorry)